# Can English "dream" be a cognate to Latin "dormatio" and Russian "dröma" "sleep"?

Tags: etymology

I could not find any relevant information on the internet except the PIE had the root dre- for sleep (Vasmer)

Comment: English wiktionary has the etymology for *dream*, and Russian wiktionary has the etymology for *дрёма*: *Родственно лат. dormiō, dormīre «спать», далее, др.-инд. drā́ti, drā́yatē «спит», греч. δαρθάνω «сплю», аор. ἔδραθε. Восходит к праиндоевр. *dre- «спать».*

Comment: @Adam Bittlingmayer American Heritage dictionary says the etymology of dream is unknown.

Comment: The key sources claiming no known etymology or a distinct etymology is "relevant information".

Comment: Completely unrelated question, are Ru да́лее, (dáleje), Ukr да́лі (dáli), etc. (comparative of *dal* "far") akin to Ger *mach dalli* "go on, hurry up; make *dalli*"? Indeed, "from Polish *dalej*" [en.wt] also cp eg. Danish *derefter* (obv ~*thereafter*), with Slav. *dal* perhaps likewise related to *dat*(I can hardly read the ru.wiktionary ety under да́лее). Cp. *telepathy*. In a very ironic way, this might be not so off-topic, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Also note Sanskr *drati* "run", which I like to cp to G *drahtig* "sporty, flexible", usually understood as "like thread [Draht]"; also cp AGr *drom* "[e.g. velo-]drome", or other words deriving "path". Alas, I'm commiting formating mistakes again--it's literally insane.

Comment: dre- doesn't look like a possible PIE root. In any case if *dream* was related to *dormio* it should have gone through Grimm's Law.

Comment: "dröma" does not seem like a Russian word to me. Could be Swedish or Elfdalian or something

Comment: @Wilson because u do not know russian

Comment: Enough to know there's no such letter as ö. But I see now you meant дрёма, not dröma.

Answer (score 1):

First, Russian *дремать* 'sleep' (*дрёма* 'a nap' is derived from this verb) and Latin dormio 'sleep' (> dormito 'feel sleepy') are cognate (Горяев; Trautmann; Преображенский; Berneker; Младенов; Boisacq; Vasmer; Machek; Slawski; Pokorny; Buck; etc.). Where did you find Latin "dormatio"?

Second, English *dream* has no plausible reconstruction even on Proto-Germanic level, ref. at least Oxford Dictionary of English. There are semantic reasons why etymologists are not eager to postulate a protoform, more on this read, for example, here: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=dream.

Since the aforesaid, *dream* is unlikely to be cognate for Russian *дрёма* and Latin *dormio* though the latter obviously are.

---

Some Russian scholars (Шанский et al) claim that German *Traum* (of which English *dream* is a cognate) shares the same root with Russian *дремать*. Nevertheless, this seems doubtful in the absence of special comments on the English etymology (see above).

Trustworthy Etymological Dictionary of Slavic Languages does not mention any German cognates:

> [image]